# Console.logging a function that sums three parameters and then console logs them out

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

The code: `x = (x,y,z) => console.log(x+y+z);console.log('x is: '+ x(2,3,5));`
The output: `'10'  x is: undefined.`
I understand that when it sees the function call, goes up and executes it with given params and that results the '10'. Then it goes again and prints the string of the console.log but when it comes to function call it returns undefined? Shouldn't it just loop back and forth between these two?

Comment: your function `x` doesn't return anything (essentially, void). when you call the second console.log, it expects `x` to return something that will be added to the string. you need to return `x+y+z`, instead of logging it

Answer (score 1):

Think about your code a little bit you're printing only and since the function `x` returns nothing nothing else could be expected to be printed

```
x = (x,y,z) => console.log(x+y+z);
console.log('x is: '+ x(2,3,5));
```

Right way

```
x = (x,y,z) => x+y+z; 
console.log('x is: '+ x(2,3,5));
```

so instead of returning nothing just return the result

Comment: I know what is the right way, i was just experimenting to see what happens. And i didnt understand it fully.

Comment: `x = (x,y,z) => console.log(x+y+z);` the function `x` returns nothing as I said it just print the the result so when you print what the function `x` returns you'll get `undefined` because the function returns nothing but when you do it like `x = (x,y,z) => x+y+z;` it means that the function should return the result so that's why it works

Answer (score 0):

Choose one console.log
Predefined in body or when you call function.
`x = (x,y,z) => { return(x+y+z) } console.log('x is: '+ x(2,3,5));`